# Remove quotes ("") from a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with several columns, all of them are character class. All values are in double quotes, I would like to remove those quotes.

Example

```
df1      df2
"1203"   "Name1"
"2304"   "Name2"
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`?

Comment: If all you want to do is remove the quotation marks, have a look at the `noquote` function.

Comment: If I omit that, I am not reading full file and getting the Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string

Comment: Then you have goofy stuff going on in your file with nested quotes or unclosed quotes that you probably need to fix before reading in the file.

Comment: The data frame contains both numbers and characters. I would like to analyze the file run some reports

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `print()` method for data frames has an option `quote=`, which you can set to `FALSE`:

```
print.data.frame(data.frame(x=c("Hello", "World")), 
                 quote=FALSE)
#       x
# 1 Hello
# 2 World
```

See also `?print.data.frame`(= help)

**Edit:**

With regards to the `dput`ed data in the comment below:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)))
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame(df=c("1203", "2304"), df2=c("Name1", "Name2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE); print(df, quote=FALSE); print(df, quote=TRUE)` works fine.

Comment: Post your data frame using `dput()` so one can inspect it.

Comment: structure(list(Col1 = c("\"2515\"", "\"3348\"", "\"3370\""), 
    Col2 = c("\"06/25/2013\"", "\"12/26/2013\"", "\"12/30/2013\""
    )), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: In your case, the quotes are part of the character vectors/strings themselves. `print(as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x))))` deleted and prints them.

Answer (score 1):

### Update dplyr 1.0.0

Since dplyr 1.0.0, you can use the new `across` syntax from `purrr` which makes it more readable for many of us.

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("\"2515\"", "\"3348\"", "\"3370\""), Col2 = c("\"06/25/2013\"", "\"12/26/2013\"", "\"12/30/2013\"" )), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame") 

df
    Col1         Col2
1 "2515" "06/25/2013"
2 "3348" "12/26/2013"
3 "3370" "12/30/2013"

df %>% 
  mutate(across(
    everything(),
    ~ map_chr(.x, ~ gsub("\"", "", .x))
  ))

  Col1       Col2
1 2515 06/25/2013
2 3348 12/26/2013
3 3370 12/30/2013
```

The advantage of this `across` syntax is that it is not only nicely readable but also very flexible. Instead of `everything()` for all columns, you can use a range of other methods to reference columns, e.g.

- by name (`Col1, Col2`)
- by data type (e.g. `is.numeric`, `is.character`)
- by other [tidyselect selection helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) (e.g. `starts_with("Col")`, `contains("Col"`)

Answer (score 0):

LukeA's answer converted my entire dataframe to characters, so I implemented this modification, which only modifies the columns that are character class:

```
character_cols = which(sapply(x, class) == 'character')

for(i in 1:length(character_cols)) {
  a = character_cols[i]
  x[,a] = gsub("\"", "", x[,a])
}
```