# How to just remove (\) from string with (\") while keeping (")?

Tags: r, stringr

Since special characters are inevitable while working data from excel.

There are so many links to eradicate special characters but when trying to remove \, we got to use \" which will eliminate both

[Remove quotes ("") from a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338114/remove-quotes-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Here, they remove both quotes but quotes at the end needs to be present.

```
> abc = c("Hi\"","Hello\\")
> abc
[1] "Hi\""   "Hello\\"

> str_replace_all(abc, "\"","")
[1] "Hi "     "Hello\\"
```

But can we have
`Hi"`  as an output ?

Comment: Do `cat(abc)`. Is that what you need?

Comment: `abc = c("Hi\"","Hello\")` is not correct, a closing " is missing

Comment: @RonakShah, Thanks, exactly, this is what is needed. However when I tried to apply the same thing to the column. It is not working

data$col = elements containing such strings
data$col = cat(data$col)

If forced using dplyr
data$col = data$col %>% mutate(col = cat(col))

**Error: Evaluation error: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'.**

Comment: @Abhi You misunderstand Ronak’s comment, and how strings work. **There is no ``\`` character in your string.** It’s part of the escape sequence for a `"` character. A syntactic workaround that allows you to have `"` in strings in R code. `cat` merely prints the actual string to the console but you don’t use it in code to work with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ronak Shah, @Chelmy88 and @Konrad Rudolph 
helped me to understand where I was wrong in interpretation.

basically, it has to do with the way R renders the string in console.

Solution using cat() can resolve the confusion.